# Must match one field and Can contain other fields in Elastic Search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to figure out on how to search items from 2 fields. We have bunch of properties and if someone selects a property to search from I will be sending that as a parameter. I tried to create those queries in kibana but couldn't combine them. Here is the sample of what I need to combine but now sure how to.

This will need to match the site field

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
        "site": {
           "query": "Some name here",
           "type": "phrase"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This will try to look in multiple fields (content, description, title, etc)

```
{
   "query": {
     "match": {
       "content": {
          "query": "diode",
          "type": "phrase"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

How would I combine both those queries (I am using NEST to query). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your mapping and an example document?

Comment: Take a look at writing queries and bool queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/search.html.